# How can I design my database to prevent my database to update if an error is produced later in the program?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a DynamoDB database to store users and a running counter of missed shifts. Essentially, each month I look at each member's data, and if they were scheduled for less than 4 shifts, I query the member from my table, increment the count, and re-add it into the database. One major problem I have with this is because I tend to edit my program frequently, the program occasionally errors out. However, sometimes this error occurs after the database was updated. How can I better design my database so that if an error occurs, it does not update the table and it only updates if the program completes successfully? By the way, all of my program is in one lambda.

One possible solution I can think of is once my lambda returns a successful execution code, it can pass the data to another lambda (SNS/SQS, streams, etc.), which would simply update the database. Are there any other more efficient solutions I'm not thinking of?

Comment: *"I query the member from my table, increment the count, and re-add it into the database."*  Note that this sounds like an anti-pattern, and will fall apart with concurrency.  DynamoDB supports [in-place increment and decrement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using two lambdas, a simpler approach is would be to restructure the code of your lambda such that it does the DynamoDB update as its last step. So, your code will look as follows (pseudo code):

```
do something
do something
...
update DynamoDB
return the result
```

Actually, at the same point in your code where you wanted to invoke the second lambda (via "SNS/SQS, streams, etc.") you can instead do the update of DynamoDB directly.

### side note

In general, if you need one lambda to invoke another lambda, the simplest way to do that is to use AWS' Lambda API which allows you to make a call to a lambda without the need to setup SNS or a stream or any other service for that matter.

Examining the Javascript API as an example (the APIs in the other languages are quite similar) you can see that it offers an [`invoke()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) method and an [`invokeAsync()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invokeAsync-property) method. The former allows you to send a request to lambda function and get a response back. the latter just sends the request without waiting for a response.

Comment: `invokeAsync` has been deprecated. You should always use `invoke` and set the `InvocationType` attribute to either `RequestResponse` or `Event` which will trigger a Lambda function synchronously or asynchronously, respectively.

Comment: With Lambda's though, if I were to invoke one from another and the parent lambda times out, would the child die as well?